# class not getting applied though detected

Tags: jquery, css

here is the code DEMO...the class replaces once but when new class is clicked the oldone should swap back

e.g on page load class of home is home1 by default then when i click on bye then class of bye gets changed to bye1 but home1 doesn't change back to home though i have a line of code removing the class home1 and add class home to it.

here's the demo

**html is**

```
<ul class=nav>
    <li class="home1"><a href="">HOME </a></li>
    <li class="bye"><a href="">BYE </a></li> 
</ul>

<script>

window.lastclickedclass="home1"; 
$("ul.nav li").click(function(e) 
{
    alert(lastclickedclass);   
    var updatedlastclass=lastclickedclass.slice(0,-1);

   var testclass=$(this).attr("class");

   var lastChar = testclass.substr(testclass.length - 1);

    if (lastChar=="1")
    {
      var newclass =  $(this).attr("class");
      var oldclass = testclass.slice(0,-1);       
    }
    else 
    {
    var newclass=$(this).attr("class")+"1";
    var oldclass=$(this).attr("class");
    }
    $(this).removeClass(oldclass);
    $(this).addClass(newclass);
      $(lastclickedclass).removeClass(lastclickedclass);  
       $(lastclickedclass).addClass(updatedlastclass);
lastclickedclass=$(this).attr("class");
    alert(lastclickedclass);   

 });
```

**css is**

```
li.home1 {
    background: #678fef no-repeat;
    width:150px;
 height:65px;
     color:#fff;
    }

li.home{ 
 background: #666 no-repeat;
 width:150px;
 height:65px;
    color:#fff;
}

li.bye1 {
    background: #678fef no-repeat;
    width:150px;
 height:65px;
     color:#fff;
    }

li.bye{ 
 background: #666 no-repeat;
 width:150px;
 height:65px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ELbCx/20/

Comment: Why window.lastclickedclass not a variable?

Comment: when local variable then it gives error of undefined this way its grabbing the lastclickedclass correctly but doesn't swap it with the updatedclass

Comment: Have you tried poking at this with the JS debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("ul.nav li").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this), clazz = $this.attr("class"), newclass, oldclass;

    var type = clazz.substr(clazz.length - 1);

    if (type == "1") {
        newclass = clazz;
        oldclass = clazz.slice(0,-1);       
    } else {
        newclass = clazz + "1";
        oldclass = clazz;
    }

    $this.removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass);

    $this.siblings('[class$="1"]').attr('class', function(idx, clazz){
        return clazz.substring(0, clazz.length - 1)
    });

    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cnzhm/)

Another version

```
var regex = /1$/
$("ul.nav li").on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this), clazz = $this.attr("class");

    e.preventDefault();

    if(!regex.test(clazz)){
        $this.removeClass(clazz).addClass(clazz + 1);
        $this.siblings('[class$="1"]').attr('class', function(idx, clazz){
            return clazz.substring(0, clazz.length - 1)
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cnzhm/2/)

Comment: i just checked it the href link doesn't work when i apply the code ...i mean when i click on "bye" it doesn't load the bye.php it continues to stay on home.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simplify your code. Instead of memorizing previous values etc, just loop through the `li` elements, look at their current class, and change accordingly. This will save you headaches when you need more than 2 elements.

I don't really like that business of adding or removing "1" on the class name, but hey, this code gets the job done, I think.

```
$("ul.nav li").click(function(e) 
{
    $("ul.nav li").each(function() {
        var curClass=$(this).attr("class");
        if (curClass.substr(curClass.length - 1) == "1") {
            var newClass = curClass.slice(0, -1);
        } else {
            var newClass = curClass + "1";
        }
        $(this).removeClass(curClass).addClass(newClass);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ELbCx/22/

Answer (score 0):

You have a small logical error in your script.

This block:

```
 if (lastChar=="1") {
      var newclass =  $(this).attr("class");
      var oldclass = testclass.slice(0,-1);       
 }
```

should be reverse:

```
if (lastChar=="1"){
      var oldclass =  $(this).attr("class");
      var newclass = testclass.slice(0,-1);       
 }
```

Also use `e.preventDefault();` in your click event to prevent default click action of anchor tag.